# Why does SQL Server query optimizer sometimes overlook obvious clustered primary key?

Tags: sql-server, sql-execution-plan

I have been scratching my head on this one.

I run as simple `select count(id)` on a table with `id` as *clustered integer primary key* and the SQL Optimizer totally ignores the primary key in it's query execution plan, in favor of an index on a date field.... ???

Actual table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[msgr](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [dt] [datetime2](3) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_msgr_dt]  DEFAULT (sysdatetime()),
    [uid] [int] NOT NULL,
    [msg] [varchar](7000) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_msgr_msg]  DEFAULT (''),
    [type] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [cid] [int] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_msgr_cid]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [via] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [msg_id] [bigint] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_msgr] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Please what could be the reason for this?

Comment: SQL Server thinks the secondary index is the better one to use in terms of performance.  Probably because the clustered index requires reading in the data pages at the leaf level.

Comment: @GordonLinoff so its no cause for concern?

Comment: The number of records in any non-clustered index (excluding filtered ones) will be the same as in the clustered index. Then one can count using the *smallest* index (by number of pages allocated) and get the correct answer, with less IO spent. This happens because 1) there is no `WHERE` clause and 2) `id` is the clustered index key (and probably primary key). `count(*)` could also leverage the same optimization.

Comment: The important thing about 2) is that it `id` is not nullable, thus `count(id)` is the same as count records (`count(*)`).

Comment: @RemusRusanu please confirm that you are saying that count(*) should work better than count(id)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) In my opinion, the key point here is that for *clustered tables* (tables which have a clustered index = the main data structure = is that data structure that store table data = clustered index is the table itself) the **every non-clustered index include also the the key of clustered index**. This means that

```
CREATE [UNIQUE] NONCLUSTERED INDEX bla 
ON [dbo].[msgr] (uid)
```

is basically the same thing as

```
CREATE [UNIQUE] NONCLUSTERED INDEX bla 
ON [dbo].[msgr] (uid) 
INCLUDE (id) -- id = key of clustered index
```

So, for such tables, every record from non-clustered indexes on the leaf pages includes also the key of clustered index. This way, within every non-clustered index and for every leaf record SQL Server store also some kind of pointer to the main data structure.

2) This means that `SELECT COUNT(id) FROM dbo.msgr` can be executed using CI but also using NCI because both indexes include the `id` (key of clustered index) column.

As a secondary note within this topic, because `IDENTITY` property (for `id` column) means a mandatory column (`NOT NULL`), `COUNT(id)` is the same thing as `COUNT(*)`. Also, this means that `COUNT(msg_id)` (also a mandatory / `NOT NULL`) column is the same thing as `COUNT(*)`. So, it's very likely that execution plan for `SELECT COUNT(msg_id) FROM dbo.msgr` will use the same NCI (for example `bla`).

3) Non-clustered indexes have smaller size than clustered index. This means also less IO => It's better from performance point of view to use the NCI than CI.

I would do following simple test:

```
SET STATISTICS IO ON;
GO

SELECT COUNT(id)
FROM dbo.[dbo].[msgr] WITH(INDEX=[bla]) -- It forces usage of NCI
GO

SELECT COUNT(id)
FROM dbo.[dbo].[msgr] WITH(INDEX=[PK_msgr]) -- It forces usage of CI
GO

SET STATISTICS IO OFF;
GO
```

If there is a lot of data within `msgr` table then `STATISTICS IO` will show different `LIO` (logical IO), with **less LIO for NCI query**.

Comment: I'll check these `STATISTICS IO` output  now. You raise an interesting point, so we need to alter our select queries as the volume of data grows? I had never thought of this

Comment: No. My point is that when number of rows is small will be {no diff | just a small diff} between CI and NCI execution plans in terms of LIO.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server has a pretty good optimizer.  If it is choosing a non-clustered index, then that is probably best for this purpose.  This is my explanation.

An index stores lists of keys and break values in an auxiliary tree-like data structure.  For non-clustered indexes, the leaves of the index are record identifiers (pointers to records).

A clustered index doesn't have leaves.  The data pages themselves are the leaves.  Hence, counting the number of records using a clustered index requires reading all the data pages.  To be honest, I might think there was a way to avoid the reading the data page reads, but reading the data pages might be necessary.

In any case, a non-clustered index doesn't require reading the original data pages, because all the information for counting is in the index.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation, but I do not follow this part "all the information for counting is in the non-clustered index." How so?

Comment: @CharlesOkwuagwu . . . Because the index contains pointers to valid records.  There is no need to peak inside the actual data to do the count.

Comment: For non-clustered indexes, the leaves of the index are record identifiers (pointers to records). Got it! Thanks!

Comment: Emphasis on **probably**. I've been in situations where optimizer is picking up PK instead of compound index etc.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server just goes through the leaves of the index for a count. It does not have to go to the data. SQL Server has chosen that index to count all the pointers to get a count.

Answer (score 1):

> I run as simple select count(id) on a table with id as clustered integer primary key and the SQL Optimizer totally ignores the primary key in it's query execution plan, in favor of an index on a date field.... ???

SQL server is a cost based optmizer,Whenever it chooses a plan,it takes two things  into account

> 1.Total cost of the query
>   2.Choosing the plan in a reasonable amount of time.

One thing SQL server query optimizer is not aware of is how many pages are there in cache.So it always assumes it has to do read them from disk..

Now considering  above things into account..

> SQL might have thought to scan the narrowest possible index since id is a primary key and this wont be null (count (id) excludes null values)plus scanning this requires to scan all of the index which is big,so instead choose to scan another index narrow one possibly which is not null.