# Select Count(*) vs Select Count(id) vs select count(1). Are these indeed equivalent?

Tags: sql-server, select, count

As a follow up to my earlier [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37636716/why-does-sql-server-query-optimizer-sometimes-overlook-obvious-clustered-primary):

Some of the answers and comments suggest that

`select count(*)` is mostly equivalent to `select count(id)` where *id is the primary key*.`

I have always favored `select count(1)`; I even always use `if exists (select 1 from table_name)` ...

**Now my question is:**

1) What is the optimal way of issuing a `select count query` over a table?

2) If we add a **where** clause: `where msg_type = X`; if `msg_type` has a *non_clustered index*, would `select count(msg_type) from table_name where msg_type = X` be the preferred option for counting?

**Side-bar:**

From a very early age, I was taught that `select * from...` is **BAD BAD BAD**, I guess this has made me skeptical of select count(*) as well

Comment: The optimizers, this days, are so advanced that probably all count queries are equivalent.

Comment: @Evgeni good point

Comment: @CharlesOkwuagwu: Just for your information, i have write a blog post on it in my blog - [https://krishnrajrana.wordpress.com/2016/02/16/sql-server-misconception-about-countcolumnname-vs-count1-vs-count/](https://krishnrajrana.wordpress.com/2016/02/16/sql-server-misconception-about-countcolumnname-vs-count1-vs-count/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
count(*)  --counts all values including nulls

count(id)-- counts this column value by excluding nulls

count(1) is same as count(*)
```

> If we add a where clause: where msg_type = X; if msg_type has a non_clustered index, would select count(msg_type) from table_name where msg_type = X be the preferred option for counting?

As i mentioned in my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37638057/2975396) ,SQL server is a cost based optimizer and the plan choosen depends on many factors .sql tries to retrieve cheapest plan in minimum time possible..

now when you issue,`count(msg_type)`,SQL **may choose** this index if this is cheaper or scan another one as long as it gives `right` results(no nulls in output)..

I always tend to use `count(*)` ,unless i want to exclude nulls

Comment: please update the link to sqlskills blog, currently it does not work

Answer (score 2):

Well, those count queries are not identical and will do different things.

```
select count(1)
select count(*)
```

Are identical, and will count every record !

```
select count(col_name)
```

Will count only `NOT NULL` values on `col_name` !

So, unless `col_name` is the `PK` as you said, those query will do different things.

As for you second question, it depends, we can't provide you a generic answer that will always be true. You will have to look at the explain plan or just check for your self, although I believe that adding this `WHERE` clause while having this index will be better.